# How does Snare! work in Netrunner?

Tags: android-netrunner

Snare! says ,"If accessed from R&D the runner must reveal it". It then allows the corp to pay 4 credits to give 3 net damage and add a tag. It also mentions to ignore this affect if Snare! is accessed from Archives.

This confuses me a little because I am not sure what to do if the card is accessed from a remote server or from HQ. Do you still get the option to give damage and a tag if it is accessed? Why then would it specifically mention R&D if there is no difference than HQ or a remote server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normally the Corp doesn't get to see what cards the runner accesses from R&D. This would mean the corp wouldn't know they could spend 4C to deal the damage! When accessed from HQ or a remote server, the Corp already knows what the card is, and so can pay 4C to deal the damage.

By making the runner reveal the card when accessed from R&D, the corp gets a chance to choose to use the ability on Snare!

The effect triggers when accessed from anywhere other than archives.

Comment: You could contrast this with "Shock", which was just printed in True Colours.  Shock has the same sort of text (if accessed from R&D the runner must reveal), but it doesn't have the caveat about archives... meaning: it still causes net damage even when accessed from the archives (in addition to when it is accessed from R&D, your hand, or a remote server)!  Throw 3 of them facedown in the archives (with a SEA Source and Scorched Earth in hand, or maybe a Punitive Counterstrike if there are actually agendas in there too). and you've just ruined a runner's day.